# Azure Data Lake Store SDK : FileStatusProperties.ChildrenNum Property always null

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake

I am trying to get the number of files in a folder using the Azure Data Store SDK (C#) but the FileStatusProperties.ChildrenNum Property is always null, and it never returns the number of children in the directory as it is supposed to do (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datalake.store.models.filestatusproperties.childrennum).
Is it a bug?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to get the number of files in a folder

I also could reproduce that you mentioned (`FileStatusProperties.ChildrenNum Property is always null`) on my side. We could give our [feedback](https://github.com/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues) to azure team. My workaround is that  we could use the following code to get the number of the files in a folder, it works correctly on my side.

```
var applicationId = "Azure AD application id";
var secretKey = "secret key";
var tenantId = "tenant Id";
var adlsAccountName = "data lake account";
var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, applicationId, secretKey).Result;
var adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds,clientTimeoutInMinutes:60);
var result = adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.ListFileStatusWithHttpMessagesAsync(adlsAccountName,
                    "/testfolder").Result; //folder path    
var count = result.Body.FileStatuses.FileStatus.Count(x => x.Type.Equals(FileType.FILE));
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. BTW, I found this workaround : `adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.GetContentSummary(adlsAccountName, "/testfolder").ContentSummary.FileCount`.

Comment: Also posted on GitHub hereafter : [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/3770)